# Copy neo4j database from python

Tags: python, copy, backup, neo4j

I need to copy an existing neo4j database in Python. I even do not need it for backup, just to play around with while keeping the original database untouched. However, there is nothing about copy/backup operations in neo4j.py documentation (I am using python embedded binding).

Can I just copy the whole folder with the original neo4j database to a folder with a new name?
Or is there any special method available in neo4j.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,
you can copy the whole DB directory when you have cleanly shut down the DB for backup.

Comment: Thanks, it worked just fine with `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree`. But it took a while to realise a stupid mistake I did: I had to shutdown the db before copying :)